# Prevent Wordpress 3.9 from adding all those classed and spans?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

The "new improved" WYSIWYG editor in Wordpress 3.9 now adds dozens if not hundreds of class and span tags with content pasted from an RTF or DOC file.  I get lots of lines like

`<p class="p5"><span class="s4"><b>Thorncrest Farm and Creamery </b></span></p>`

Which, in 3.8 would have gotten me

`<p><b>Thorncrest Farm and Creamery </b></p>`

So now I need to paste the RTF into WP, switch to code view, copy all the garbage into Sublime Text and user the Tag plugin to strip all the spans and classes. Some improvement.

Before anyone suggests it, I can't past as plain text since the writer has given me copy with B and I tags throughout, which I don't want to have to hunt down and re-apply.

Ideas?

Comment: Very annoying "feature"!